# After Transition, Release Bitmap from Memory

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, bitmap, imageview

I am fading between different `Bitmaps` on an `ImageView`, and would like to recycle / release the image from the old `Bitmap` which is no longer visible in the `ImageView` after the transition.

```
final Bitmap newBitmap = //this is a bitmap
final Bitmap oldBitmap = //this is a bitmap
final Drawable oldDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), oldBitmap);
final Drawable newDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mBitmap);

Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[]{oldDrawable, newDrawable};
final TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(drawables);

this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mImage.setImageDrawable(td);
        td.startTransition(1000);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
                oldBitmap.recycle();
          }
        }, 1050);
    }
});
```

When I try to recycle the old `Bitmap` after the transition has ended, I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap

Is there a way to recycle a `Bitmap` after the transition has completed so that the memory can be released without causing an error?

Note: As the transition goes through multiple images, eventually the device runs out of memory as the previously set `Bitmaps` are not released even though they are no longer visible.

Comment: can you post the code you're trying to `recycle` the `Bitmap` with?

Comment: @BartekLipinski When I add mBitmap.recycle(); after the transition has the error occurs. I have updated the code in the post. Any ideas?

Comment: but the `td` goes from `oldDrawable` to `newDrawable` and the `newDrawable` uses `mBitmap`

Comment: @BartekLipinski That was a typo when I typed it into the post. Just updated the post to reflect the proper logic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your `td` is still holding (and using) the `oldDrawable` even though it is not displaying it.

I would suggest calling:

```
mImage.setImageDrawable(newDrawable);
```

just before recycling the `oldBitmap`. That way your `td` shouldn't be used anymore and `oldBitmap` should be easily recycled.